# ggplot 2 plot bar change axis from numeric to categorical

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe like this:

```
item    count
1       50
2       158
3       147
```

When I used ggplot to make a bar chart, it showed the x-xis as 2.5, 5.0,... How can I make it show only the values in my dataframe:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = item, y = count))+ geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=factor(item), y=count)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Should do the trick.